# Snapcraft - how do I use an absolute path to files of a previous part

Tags: compiling, snap

I'm creating a Snap which contains 2 parts.
The second part needs files that have been created in the first part otherwise it will not build.

I tried to use a relative path, starting in the root directory of the current part, but libtool does not accept it.
If I use the absolute path it builds but now the snapcraft.yaml is not portable anymore.

This is what I have now:

```
build: |
  ./autogen.sh && ./configure LDFLAGS='-L/home/snapcraft/mySnap/parts/libdb4.8/install/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/' CPPFLAGS='-I/home/snapcraft/mySnap/parts/libdb4.8/install/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include/'
```

Is there an environmental variable that holds the absolute path of previous parts?
Or is there any other way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the necessary files to the staging area

```
stage:
  - usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/*
  - usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include/*
```

and then pointing to them using the $SNAPCRAFT_STAGE environment variable.

```
build: |
  ./autogen.sh && ./configure LDFLAGS='-L$SNAPCRAFT_STAGE/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib/' CPPFLAGS='-I$SNAPCRAFT_STAGE/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include/'
```